# how to control the display format of content of more java doc @see

Tags: java, javadoc

I have java doc for a method:

```
 *  @see <a href="http://path/to/A">A</a>
 *  @see <a href="http://path/to/B">B</a>
 *  @see <a href="http://path/to/C">C</a>
```

display as:

```
See Also:
a, b , c
```

how can I get them display in multi line as

```
See Also:
a  
b 
c
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where? this shows as multiple lines in eclipse. Do you mean real generated javadoc html?

Comment: I test it in IntelliJ IDEA CE

Comment: a bit simpler to write than a list: `@see <br><a href="http://path/to/B">B</a>` - shows empty lines between in eclipse though.